# How to draw routes in Open Street Map using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, openstreetmap

I have a lot of data (lattitude and longitude coordinates) in mysql.

I want to plot a route ( for example: From A to F, via BCDE ) for those coordinates AND add Markers for some coordinates in OSM using PHP.

Can somebody tell me where can I begin? I've not worked with OSM before. I have to switch to OSM, because of limitations in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't give us any information about the data you want to display/calculate/...?

If you just want to use osm tiles instead of google maps and display some paths on it take a look at Leaflet: http://leafletjs.com